# Блокировка кнопки "ВХОД"

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть форма:

```
<form name="auth_form" method="post" action="" class="form_login">
<input class="text" name="login" id="login" type="text" value="Логин" >
<input class="text" name="password" id="password" type="password" value="Пароль" >
<input id="form_enter_btn" type="submit" value="Вход" class="submit pink">
</form>
```

Нужно написать функцию на `JQuery` что бы кнопка входя была неактивна и к ней добавлялся класс `"disabled"`. Если поле логин содержит надпись `"Логин"` или пустое и пароль содержит надпись `"Пароль"` или пустое.. Тоесть если я поля не заполненны или заполненно только одно из них - кнопка вход блокируется и добавляется класс...
Причём изначально что бы кнопка блокировалась средствами JS при загрузке, а то если у человека отключен JS то он не смложет войти...

Comment: А обязательно писать на JQuery на нативе нельзя?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
    <title>Работа за автора :)</title>
    <style>
        .submit_visible{
            visibility: visible;
        }
        .submit_hidden{
            visibility: hidden;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function check(){
            if(flags[0] && flags[1]){
                form_enter_btn.className = "submit_visible";
                auth_form.setAttribute("disabled","");
            }
            else{
                form_enter_btn.className = "submit_hidden";
                auth_form.removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
        }
        window.onload = function(){
            flags = [false,false];
            auth_form = document.getElementById("auth_form");
            form_enter_btn = document.getElementById("form_enter_btn");
            login = document.getElementById("login");
            password = document.getElementById("password");
            form_enter_btn.className = "submit_hidden";
            login.onkeyup = function () {
            flags[0] = login.value.length > 0 && login.value != "Логин";
            check();
            };
            password.onkeyup = function () {
                flags[1] = password.value.length > 0 && password.value != "Пароль";
                check();
            };
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="auth_form" method="post" action="" class="form_login">
    <input class="text" name="login" id="login" type="text" value="Логин" >
    <input class="text" name="password" id="password" type="password" value="Пароль" >
    <input id="form_enter_btn" type="submit" value="Вход" class="submit_visible">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Работа за автора)

Comment: насколько видно - функция срабатывает только при загрузке странице, она не работает на изменение, если человек начал вводить логин а потом пароль, да и ещё судя по функции если будет логин пустой, а пароль заполнен то всёравно кнопка будет доступна...

Comment: @Oll теперь всё правильно работает!  
P.S
 
>насколько видно - функция срабатывает только при загрузке странице
чем вы смотрели :)

Comment: window.onload - вот это срабатывает только при первой загрузке страницы... и больше не срабатывает... А мне ндо было ещё и на изменение диамическое... это-же форма в ней проверку сделать на активность кнопки. а она получается при загрузке вывела что она неактивна и всё... а изменяй не изменяй в ней данные - оно не меняет своего решения...

Comment: Вы перед тем как позорится подучите JavaScript или хотя бы откройте код в браузере...
  
    login.onkeyup = function () {...} //Видите это?
    password.onkeyup = function(){...} //А это?

Comment: onkeyup зато работает при нажатии клавиш

Comment: Прошу прощения - затупил... p.s. ничего позорного в том что я не знаю JS нет. Просто не моя сфера. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: А что будет, если нажатая кнопка это "enter"? :)

P.S. Подсказка, кнопка submit никак не блокируется, а просто скрывается. После "enter" форма успешно будет отправляться - весело подмигивая спрятанной кнопке "submit".

Comment: Да тут собственно я уже сам дописал... и немного подправил... добавил $("#form_enter_send").attr("disabled", true); и $("#form_enter_send").removeAttr("disabled");

Comment: хм...

    flags = [false,false]; // где var?

про остальные переменные уже молчу

а как на счёт такого варианта?

    flags[0] = login.value.length > 0 && login.value != "Логин"
    flags[1] = password.value.length > 0 && password.value != "Пароль"

Comment: Spectre:  
var нет потому что я объявляю глобальную переменную
а насчёт условий... я спешил (ведь кроме Хэшкод'а есть лицей)
теперь улучшил код спасибо...

Answer (score 6):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#btN").toogleClass("disabled");
    jQuery("#login, #pass").keypress(function() {
        var login = jQuery("#login").val()
        var pass = jQuery("#pass").val()
        if (login != '' && pass !='')
        {
            jQuery("#btN").toogleClass("disabled");
        }
    });
})
```

После нажатия кнопки можно сделать проверку с использованием плагина [ajax form submit](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/), на событие beforeSubmit выводить предупреждение о не заполнении

Comment: зачем плагины? есть же колбэк `beforeSend` у [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Можно и так